# strtok fails to tokenize?

Tags: c, strtok

In the following, I'm trying to split string without creating copies using `strok`

```
#include <string.h>

void func(char *c)
{
    char *pch = strtok (c,"#");

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        pch = strtok (NULL, "#");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char c[] = "a#a\nb#b\n";

    char *pch = strtok (c,"\n");

    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        char *p = new char[strlen(pch)+1];
        strcpy(p, pch);

        func(p); //copy of pch

        pch = strtok (NULL, "\n"); //fails to get pointer to 'b#b'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm... `strtok()` may store the tokenized string in a static buffer. Hence, when second `strtok()` is called in the `func()`, the results of the first operation (in the `main()`) seem to be lost. Take a look at `strtok_r()`.

Comment: On a side (and possibly irrelevant) note, I don't really understand why you mix C and C++ code. You could have made your life a tad easier if you used STL strings and boost libraries.

Comment: would you like to provide a link to `strtok_r()` implementation?

Comment: @Dave18: it actually is a part of POSIX.1-2001, so if you're writing code for *NIX, it is already there, you may take a look at its man page. If you're programming for Windows, they've got `strtok_s()` there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftsafwz3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

strtok use static variables, therefore it cannot work reentrant and is never threadsafe.
strtok_r is not C89/C99 only POSIX.